# CSharp convert .cs class into .dll

Tags: c#, cities-skylines-api

I'm trying to convert a mod that I made for Cities Skylines into a .dll, but I don't know how. (I'm using Visual Studio). People are saying click 'Project' then 'Output' but I don't see that option. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzI1o.jpg

Also people are saying use a CMD command, 'csc', but when I run that, it's an unrecognised command by Windows.

It's just a C# Class file.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for a tutorial to Visual Studio. There are a *lot* of tutorials, eg try Microsoft's own MSDN site, or start from the Help menu inside Visual Studio itself. The type of project that creates dlls is the "Class Library" Project

Comment: If anyone ever comes across this and has the same problem as OP, lookup adding csc to your path (or run it from its directory).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using a class library project, if you are not, make one and move your files into that first.

If you are using visual studio then Simply go to Build > Configuration Manager and change the Active solution configuration to Release, then Go Build > Build Solution. Under the folder where your project is located you should see a folder called bin > Release, your .dll should be there

Comment: If the OP used a Class Library Project there would be no problem - a dll is created whether you use Debug or Release build

Comment: Thanks for the feed back, I see all of these options now, and it worked, sorta. 
But, when I go to that folder, there's no .dll there, and I press 'Build Solution'.

Comment: Since you accepted my answer should I assume you got it to work? or is it still not showing up?

Comment: I finally got it to work, I missing DLL references, and it wasn't compiling correctly, my mistake. But yes, thank you very much, your solution worked, and I'm able to find the .DLL. :) Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a new Class Library Project.

File -> New Project -> Class Library Project

Your main project csfile :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

csc is the command line C sharp compiler: [C# compiler options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

Usage:

```
csc /target:library /reference:..\MyClass.dll
```